# Schwarz Lemma Application

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, analytic-geometry

I'm trying to work on the following application of the Schwarz Lemma, however, I can make no progress in finding the solution beyond finding a map that allows me to apply the Schwarz Lemma. Can Anyone help?

Suppose $f$ is analytic on the disk and makes the disk into the disk. Suppose also that $f(1/2) = 1/8$. What is the largest possible value for $|f(3/4i)|$?

In order to apply the Schwarz lemma, Ive set 
$$
g(x) = (\phi_{1/8} \circ f \circ \phi_{1/2})(z),
$$
where
$$
\phi_{\alpha}(z) = \frac{\alpha - z}{1 - \overline{\alpha} z}, |\alpha| < 1.
$$

Then $g$ maps 0 to 0 and so we can apply the Schwarz Lemma to $g$ to see that $|g(z)| \leq |z|$ for all $|z| < 1$.

The issues is the composition of $f$ on the left by $\phi_{1/8}$; it prevents me to getting anything beyond $|g(3/4i)| \leq 3/4$.

Comment: $f = \phi_{1/8}^{-1}\circ g\circ \phi_{1/2}^{-1}$.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp I know, but I haven't been able to again any information when playing around with that identity and the Schwarz lemma, I'm afraid; that's what's frustrating me.

Comment: Say, the value of $\phi_{1/2}^{-1}(3/4i)$ (actually, do you mean (3/4)i or 3/(4i) ?) is $w$. Then you only have to find the image of the circle with radius $|w|$ under $\phi_{1/8}^{-1}$. This is because of $|f(3/4i)| = |\phi_{1/8}^{-1}(g(w))| = |\phi_{1/8}^{-1}(re^{it})|$ with $r\le |w|$.